# Appropriate http status code for confirmation

Tags: http, httpresponse

I'm implementing an API for a several different client programs to connect to, and I want the api to be able to send back an "are you sure you want to do this?" message, such as when trying to delete something via the api. Looking over the list of established http response codes, I don't see one that seems quite appropriate. I could always skip using a code and provide some other manner of communicating the confirmation, but I would really like to use a standardized method if possible.

The api is normally accessed via a client application, currently a JavaScript-powered one, but I've also made it so that it can be effectively used by directly accessing the api via web browser url.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In what regard would the "Yes I'm sure"-message differ from the "Delete entity 42" message? What would keep clients from immediately sending the "Yes I'm sure"-message? Does your API get accessed by machines or humans?

IMHO this should be solved in the user interface, not in the transport layer.

Comment: The "Yes I'm sure" message would be the same as the delete message with an additional flag to indicate to go ahead. There is nothing to stop a client from immediately sending a "yes, I'm sure" message when requesting a delete, and I'm okay with that. It currently is implemented in the ui layer, I'm experimenting with having it in the api instead (which could be considered a ui of sorts).

Comment: It is not what anyone would expect, but if you're sure: you can for example use a custom header like `Accept-confirm: confirm-delete`, and return [`406 Not Acceptable`](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-10.4.7) if the `Accept-confirm` header is not what you expect.

Comment: I hadn't even thought of using a header. I had considered 406 before, but I needed a way to communicate that it was a confirmation that was needed. I'm still a bit on the fence as to whether I want to implement it this way, but at least now I have a good idea how to do it. Thanks!

Comment: somehow this is the correct answer, but Sometimes it will be related to business. 
Like this operation will cost you 15 $ in some time and sometime will cost you 50 $
so this message should be exposed by the server and not the application

Comment: @Basil that's an interesting take, but one that can be modeled as well. You mean that you want to include a "What If"-header or endpoint, so the server can return "This operation would cost you X when executed"?

Comment: I'm not talking about the header  put the header as you want 
I'm talking about business and the HTTP status code should be customized 
because as the giving example, sometimes user may cancel the operation if the operation cost him 10$ but if the operation cost him 50 he will not take the action
so the status of HTTP should be exposed after doing some business functions

Comment: @Basil you've lost me there. I'm not sure how a status code will help there.